# Automatically Detect Server Name of Machine in App.config

Tags: c#, entity-framework, deployment, app-config, desktop-application

I am developing a Desktop Application in C#. An I want to use MSSQL Server Database in it through Entity Framework. I want to know that how can I make app-config file automatically detect server name in Connection String tag. As when I will deploy my application through a setup. It will install on another machine. It may have different server name. So I want my app-config to automatically detect the server name available on that machine. I knew there was a way but I have forgotten it. Please help me here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to. You can refer to a local database like this:

```
.\SQLEXPRESS
```

The whole connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ActiveConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NameOfTheDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Yeah but I am using Entity Framework in my project. So I have used CreateIfNotExists function in it. Now when it will run on another machine. Every time it will have to connect to database using connection string which is located in app.config. Server Name on my pc is DESKTOP-UDP1R92. It will definitely be different on the other machine. I am asking how can I program my application to automatically get server name in app.config file

Comment: Well, the connection string is up for you to modify before you make a connection to a database. Getting the host name at run time is documented. But again, the local host you can refer to using a dot.